# Confusion over elasticnet: feature selection not performed as expected

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, lasso, glmnet, elastic-net

I am a little confused in interpreting the results of regularization. Could someone please explain in a relatively basic way why I get these results and what it is that I'm misunderstanding?

I have run 14 different models, with each one including one additional predictor variable. for example model1 <- DV ~ variable1, model2 <- DV ~ variable1 + varaible2, etc...

To build each model I used elasticnet which is a combination of ridge and lasso regularization, and cross validated each model on a training set to get the optimal parameters which are then evaluated on an independent testing set. This procedure is repeated multiple times across different training and testing sets. The mean performance of each model on the testing set after cross validation is used to select the best model. There are the results in the AUC of the testing set for each model:

```
model1  model2  model3  model4  model5  model6  model7  model8  model9 model10 model11 model12 model13 model14 
0.621   0.606   0.617   0.629   0.638   0.647   0.648   0.656   0.648   0.639   0.640   0.634   0.632   0.632
```

You can see that the predictive power of the models increases as a new variable is added (excluding model2) up to model8, then after model8 the predictive power decreases incrementally with each variable.

MY QUESTION: Why does the performance of the models start to decrease as new predictors are added after model8?

Reason for my confusion: Elasticnet is a combination of ridge and lasso, and I understand that lasso introduces sparsity in the coefficients by reducing some of them to 0. So, this being true, elastic net should have selected the lasso parameter (alpha = 0) for models 9 to 14 which would have reduced the additional coefficients from the newly added variables to 0, and therefore these models should have had the same performance on the testing set as model8 (because the only effective coefficients are those from models 1 to 8).

One reason why this is particularly important is also because I had previously believed that with elasticnet, one can just 'throw' all variables into the same model and get the best results because elasticnet will take care of feature selection for you, however these results suggest that this isn't the case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How much data do you have?

Comment: @jbowman 3821 cases. So quite a lot!

Comment: Adding useless variables to your model always hurts in the long run; you can't count on elastic net / lasso to eliminate them completely 100% of the time in finite samples.  The L1 norm is not omniscient, after all!  I admit 3821 cases is a lot, though, and I might have expected better performance, but some of that will depend on correlation between variables and what, exactly, they are.

Comment: @jbowman I see your point, however doesn't this mean that regularization cannot be used for feature selection? I had assumed that lasso can be used to determine what the useless variables are...

Comment: Sure!  It would be interesting to compare your results with those from the same model estimated without regularization, too.  That would show that you are deriving a fair amount of benefit, I hope / expect, even though it's not perfect.

Comment: @jbowman, yes, however I'm experiencing perfect separation with regular LR, typically I would find that the AUC's get higher for the separated variables, and models 9 to 14 would have the same or higher AUC's as model8.